# Stored Procedure with dapper.net is slower than EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dapper

I have been replacing Entity Framework and LINQ queries with dapper.net as a means of data access with great success, I am seeing real improvements in speed.  However when I try the same with a stored procedure, the result is the opposite, I get a `Timeout expired` error every time:

The stored procedure itself is unchanged so it's clearly not the issue, suffice to say it returns 2 result sets: data and a rowcount.  It is used to populate a jquery datatable.  This is the code used to call the proc:

```
public DapperQueryMultipleModel GetStockCatalogueDatatable_WIP(DatatableFilterModel model)
{
    DapperQueryMultipleModel returnModel = new DapperQueryMultipleModel();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@storeId", model.Store);
    // more params..
    p.Add("@TotalRowsCount", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    using (var connection = _context.Database.Connection)
    {
        using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("dbo.StockCatalogueDatatable", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
           returnModel.TableData = multi.Read<dynamic>().ToList();
           returnModel.RowCount = multi.Read<int>().Single();
        }
     }
     return returnModel;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have more cases with QueryMultiple?

Comment: Yes I use QueryMultiple a lot, but always with a query string, not a SP. I changed the dynamic return type to a class and that made a big improvement.